# Google search issue in Python

Tags: python, google-maps

I have implemented a program in python which performs the Google search and captures top ten links from the search results. I am using 'pygoogle' library for search, when I am implementing my program for the first two or three times, it is getting proper hits and the entire project is working very fine. But afterward, after certain links got downloaded, it's giving an error as follows. (gui_two.py is my program name)

Exception in Tkinter callback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1413, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "gui_two.py", line 113, in action
    result = uc.utilcorpus(self.fn1,"")
  File "/home/ci/Desktop/work/corpus/corpus.py", line 125, in utilcorpus
    for url in g1.get_urls():   #this is key sentence based search loop
  File "/home/ci/Desktop/work/corpus/pygoogle.py", line 132, in get_urls
    for result in  data['responseData']['results']:
  TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I know this is most familiar error in python, but I am not able to do anything since it is a library. I wonder my program is spamming the Google or I need custom Google search API's or may be the other reason. Please give me precise information for performing search without any issue. I will be so grateful for your help.

Thanks.

Edited: Actually my code is very huge, here is a small piece of code, where problem arises.

```
  g1 = pygoogle(query)  
  g1.pages = 1
  for url in g1.get_urls(): #error is in this line
      print "URL : ",url
```

It may work if we simply copy it in a simple .py file, but if we execute it many times, program gives an error.

Comment: It seems to me like you get empty results. Can you put the code there so we can see what could be wrong?

Comment: Show us the code, otherwise we are just guessing.

Comment: I have added a small code, please have a look on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by modifying the source code of pygoogle.py library program. The bug in this code is, whether an element has the data or none is not checked in the code. The modified code is:

def get_urls(self):

```
    """Returns list of result URLs"""
    results = []
    for data in self.__search__():
        #following two lines are added to fix the issue
        if data['responseData'] == None or data['responseData']['results'] == None:
            break
        for result in  data['responseData']['results']:
            if result:
                results.append(urllib.unquote(result['unescapedUrl']))
    return results
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the culprit code from pygoogle.py (from http://pygoogle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pygoogle.py)

```
def get_urls(self):
    """Returns list of result URLs"""
    results = []
    search_results = self.__search__()
    if not search_results:
        self.logger.info('No results returned')
        return results
    for data in search_results:
        if data and data.has_key('responseData') and data['responseData']['results']:
            for result in  data['responseData']['results']:
                if result:
                    results.append(urllib.unquote(result['unescapedUrl']))
    return results
```

Unlike every other place where `data['responseData']['results']` is used, they're not both being checked for existence using `has_key()`.

I suspect that your `responseData` is missing `results`, hence the for loop fails.

Since you have the source, you can edit this yourself.

Also make an issue for the project - very similar to [this](https://code.google.com/p/pygoogle/issues/detail?id=4&can=1) one in fact.

Comment: Yes, you are correct I did modify the source code of pygoogle, I posted the answer. It is working fine. Thanks :)